# CPU Utilization reaching 100%

Tags: sql-server-2008

Whenever Insertion and Updations operations are happening on Database from Application end users , SQL Server CPU utlization goes high

When i checked for Blockings there are not much deadlock as lock is released immediately so CPU fluctuates

My problem is that when I run the query CPU utilization of my database server reaches up to 100% until the process finishes.

Please help me in understanding best practice for this kind of scenarios.

Comment: Why is that a problem, per se? You're actually *using* the full capacity of your server. That's not automatically a bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check for the Wait Type for this session

   2. If your Query uses Temp DB (Temp Tables or Temporary Table Variables) then check is there any Page Contention.
   3. Check is there any spinlock
   4. Check for IO and Time Statistics
   5. Check your query whether are you able to introduce any new index by using Execution Plan
   6. Check the data transfer speed between your I/O and Memory
   7. Check whether are you able to increase your Memory
   8. Check MDP
   9. Check for a few counters to validate
      a. Page Life Expectancy
      b. Pages Read/Sec
      c. Pages Write/Sec
      d. Free list stalls/sec
      e. Lazy writes/sec
      f. Checkpoint pages/sec
      g. Page lookups/sec
      h. Buffer cache hit ratio
      i. Memory Grants Pending